# Create new table from records with shared values

Tags: mysql

I have a table where two or more records share a common field:

```
Bob | NY
Mary| NY
Dan | NY
Ed  | CA
Ben | CA
```

and I want to make a new table with the records that share a common value as Field1 and Field2:

```
Bob  | Mark
Bob  | Dan
Mary | Dan
Ed   | Ben
```

I'm not sure how to do a Create Table as Select to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this select

```
SELECT t1.num as num1,t2.num as num2
FROM tab1 t1, tab1 t2
WHERE t1.code = t2.code
AND t1.num < t2.num
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c6839/2)

question was updated, but same query would still work.

```
SELECT t1.name as name1,t2.name as name2
FROM tab1 t1, tab1 t2
WHERE t1.code = t2.code
AND t1.name < t2.name
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29fdc/2)

Comment: edited my question since clearly I confused the issue using numbers in the field vale sorry

Comment: Yessir, used the core code/concept just removed the < and it worked great. Just wanted to make sure the question was clearer for future users.

Comment: I was not aware < works with strings. Exactly what does it indicate? It is analogous to "!="?

Comment: it just compares them alphabetically.  if you use != you'll have things like Bob, Mary and Mary, Bob, where if you use < you'll only get Bob, Mary

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.n na, b.n nb from t  a join t b on b.m = a.m and b.n > a.n
```

Comment: I edited my question since clearly I confused the issue using numbers in the field vale sorry

Comment: Seeing as this is functionally identical to the accepted answer, clearly you didn't !

Comment: Clearly I didn't what? I edited the question to remove the numeric values.

Comment: Erm 'confuse the issue'

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks for your answer and clatification